# SAS - Update table variable with multiple where criteria

Tags: sql, sas

Please excuse my lack of knowledge i'm very new to SAS.

I have two tables as exampled below:

**T1**

| ID | Ill_No |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

**T2**

| ID | Ill_No |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

I want to update the original table with a new variable (MATCH) where both ID and Ill_No match with the second table. Example below:

**T1**

| ID | Ill_No | MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 3 | Y |
| 2 | 3 | Y |

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use a simple [`merge`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1i8w2bwu1fn5kn1gpxj18xttbb0.htm) statement

```
data want;
merge t1(in=one) t2(in=two);
by id III_No;
if one and two then match = 'Y';
run;
```

```
ID  III_No  match
1     1       Y
1     1       Y
1     2 
1     2 
1     3 
1     3 
2     1 
2     1 
2     2 
2     2 
2     3       Y
2     3       Y
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly and is very quick for over 20m rows.